# Rails Join Query Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm struggling to make a query that shows the friends of user that have activities in a city.
The variable @friends has the friends of the user, and i want to make a join with activities and and places because i want to filter the results by city. A account(user) has many activities and also has many places though activities.
I'm having the following error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: accounts.city:

   def show
        @friends = Account.find(current_account.id).active_friends
        @nearbyFriends = @friends.joins(:activities,:places).where(:city => @place.city).group(:account_id)
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def show
  # ...
  @nearbyFriends = @friends.joins(:activities,:places).where(:places => { :city => @place.city }).group(:account_id)
end
```

When using `joins`, any field in `where` clause must contain table name it comes from. The same applies to `group` (if friends table doesn't contain `account_id`).

Comment: SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: account_id

Comment: Which one of your tables contain `account_id`?

Comment: Then as I told you, the same applies to `group`, so in this case `group("activities.account_id")`.